# Viewing .rpt file

Tags: crystal-reports, report, katalon-studio, test-suite, rpt

I'm working in Katalon Studio, where my Test Suite Collection gives me a report as .rpt file.

The question is, how can I read that .rpt file?

I've found some questions about it on stackoverflow, some recommends to use Crystal Reports but how I see that software is not free. I also tried FFV (Free File Viewer) and Axure for viewing my .rpt files, but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is implemented yet in Katalon Studio. As far as I can see, Test Suite Collection (TSC) report only gives you the start and end times for the TSC execution.

TSC in Katalon Studio is merely, as the name suggests, a collection of Test Suites (TS).

TS are what the execution is centered around, so TSC only runs multiple TS, and you can see the test reports for the each individual TS, but not the TSC.